# Call spring inject class from a static method from another class

Tags: java, spring

Well, i have a class with @Component anotation, this class makes some selects in database, see:

```
@Component(value = "parametroRelatorioHelper")
public class ParametroRelatorioHelper {

    @Autowired
    private BasicDAO dao;

    public ParametroRelatorio getParametroByNome(String nome) {

        List<ParametroRelatorio> parametros = (List<ParametroRelatorio>) dao
                .findByNamedQuery(ParametroRelatorio.FIND_BY_NOME,
                        new NamedParams("nome", nome));

        if (parametros.size() > 0)
            return parametros.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }

    public List<ParametroRelatorio> getAll() {

        return (List<ParametroRelatorio>) dao
                .findByNamedQuery(ParametroRelatorio.FIND_ALL);

    }

    public BasicDAO getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(BasicDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
}
```

Now, i have a "Helper" class, where user can call your method directly (static method) but i need call a method from ParametroRelatorioHelper, see:

```
public class ReportHelper {
  public static void call(){
      //how can i do it without @Component injection
      parametroRelatorioHelper.getAll();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this helper? Just inject the `ParametroRelatorioHelper` bean where you need it.

Comment: So, think about it i see that only way is put @Component annotation in my class. I thought to build a Bussiness Delegate Pattern and avoid it but i don't have time to this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your architecture is incorrect, instead the ReportHelper should be a component too and the dependencies should be injected in it, otherwise it collides with the idea of the Spring IOC, helper methods should not rely on components on services...